# MS Access - DateSerial?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I apologize in advance because I don't know how to properly ask this question.

I am using access to pull in data from several tables and want to filter/query the data by the first 10 days in any month, in any year. I understand that I could use operators to say something like:

> =#1/1/2017# and <=#1/10/2017 Or >=#2/1/2017# and <=#2/10/2017# Or....on and on

But that would be a long expression. Is there something easy I could do using DateSerial, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Day Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/day-function-6c7fa9a6-15e6-4e64-b45a-01e9338b9415) *Returns a Variant (Integer) specifying a whole number between 1 and 31, inclusive, representing the day of the month.*

So use that function in your query's `WHERE` clause ...

```
WHERE Day(YourDateField) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to do a little more research to understand how to insert this into the SQL view (that's how new I am to this), but it did work. I up-voted you, but my rep is too low to change your score.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE DatePart("d", [MyColumn]) > DatePart("d", #01/01/2018#)
    AND DatePart("d", [MyColumn]) < DatePart("d", #01/11/2018#)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. Do I just type it into the Criteria under the Field I want to use it on? I'm just learning to use Access.

Comment: I hadn't figured out the SQL view before HansUp posted his suggestion, which required less typing and worked, so I didn't try your solution, but I'm thankful for your response.